# Can't get correct server response on validation error (spectree + flask )

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a problem with my API on Flask, using spectree.
I have one endpoint with one "POST" method, which takes some data, validates it, and if successful, returns `{"status": "OK"}`, and in case of validation error, returns a 400 code and a message that there was a validation error. It is rather not what I have, but what I wanted to achieve. I suggest taking a look at the code to better understand what I mean:

```py
from flask import Flask
from spectree import SpecTree, Response
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Error(BaseModel):
    code:int = 400
    message:str = 'Validation Failed'

class Unit(BaseModel):
    id: int

app = Flask(__name__)
api = SpecTree('flask', app=app, title='API', version='v1.0', path='docs')

@app.post('/imports')
@api.validate(json=Unit, validation_error_status=400, resp=Response(HTTP_400=Error))
def imports():
    return {'status': 'OK'}, 200
```

That is, as you can see, following the documentation, I set `validation_error_status=400` so that when validation fails, the client receives a response with a 400 code (wow?). I also set `resp=Response(HTTP_400=Error)` so that when a 400 error occurs, the client receives an Error response. Thus, on a validation error, the API client should receive a response corresponding to the Error model (see below)

Now, if I send a request that is not valid, that is, `id` will not be int, but for example "fkfld", I will receive the following response:

```json
[
  {
    "loc": [
      "id"
    ],
    "msg": "value is not a valid integer",
    "type": "type_error.integer"
  }
]
```

I thought the answer would be:

```json
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Validation Failed"
}
```

I use:

- Python 3.8.3
- Flask 2.1.2
- spectree 0.10.0

I tried very hard to understand what my mistake was, but I could not. I've read the documentation, but my problem is only related to:

> What is Response and how to use it?
>
> To build a response for the endpoint, you need to declare the status code with format HTTP_{code} and corresponding data (optional).

Please help me figure this out, I really want to understand my mistakes and how to do it right.

Comment: Interestingly, `@app.errorhandler(400)` doesn't help...

Comment: Are you able to get the Flask [examples from the documentation](https://github.com/0b01001001/spectree/tree/master/examples) working? Do they help?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't have what I need.

Comment: What do you see as the difference between the documentation examples and your example? What happens if you try to modify an example gradually until it resembles what you're trying to do - at what point does it break down?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought I already answered your question. The thing is, the example doesn't have what I'm looking for, namely; "How can I return an Error response on validation error (i.e. a JSON with a code field and a message field)" In the example, this case is not handled